# How can I make async await work for the attached code?

Tags: javascript, async-await

Can anyone tell me how can I make async await work for the below code:

```
const posts = [
  { title: "Post One", body: "This is post one" },
  { title: "Post Two", body: "This is post two" },
];

function getPosts() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    posts.forEach((post) => {
      console.log(post.title, post.body);
    });
  }, 1000);
}

function createPost(post) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    posts.push(post);
  }, 2000);
}

async function init() {
  await createPost({ title: "Post Three", body: "This is post three" });
  getPosts();
}

init();
```

Currently I cannot see the third post as createPost does not wait for getPosts.

Comment: `await` is not for waiting for a timeout to tick, but for a promise to resolve. You didn't create a promise.

Comment: `createPost()` should return a promise. See the basic example at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Comment: You'll have to create and return a promise from `createPost` and `getPosts`. `await` can't msgically await everything, only if it's told what to await...

Answer (score 1):

Your `createPost` method should return a Promise and then after `setTimeout` is executed you can resolve that promise and `getPosts` method execution inside of init method will then wait for `createPost` to be resolved.

```js
const posts = [{
    title: "Post One",
    body: "This is post one"
  },
  {
    title: "Post Two",
    body: "This is post two"
  },
];

function getPosts() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    posts.forEach((post) => {
      console.log(post.title, post.body);
    });
  }, 1000);
}

function createPost(post) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    console.log('called createPost')
    
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('resolving createPost')
      posts.push(post);
      resolve(true);
    }, 2000);
  })
}

async function init() {
  // this will make sure the rest of the code waits for createPost to be resolved
  await createPost({
    title: "Post Three",
    body: "This is post three"
  });
  
  // this will only run after createpost is resolved
  getPosts();
}

init();
```